# converting orthogonal set to orthonormal set

Tags: matrices, vectors, orthonormal

Verify that the set of vectors:

```
  {(5,0), (0,5)}
```

is orthogonal with respect to the inner product:

```
 < u, v > = 4u1v1 + u2v2 on R2 ;
```

then convert it to an orthonormal set by normalizing the vectors.

I thought this would be simple, but it has proven to be more complicated than i thought. I must not understand part of the process. I verified that the set was orthogonal by

```
0 = 4(5*0) + (0*5)
```

now to make theses vectors orthonormal I followed this formula:

```
||V|| = < V, V >^1/2 = ( 4V1V1 + V2V2 )^1/2
```

and my results were as follows:

{(1/2,0), (0,1)}

But no matter how I give it to the computer it wont take it. Is this incorrect?

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: looks correct to me. which software and language are you using? would you like to show us your code?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Im not coding this. Im taking a class and the homework is online. Im going to assume that Its just user input error on my end or they messed up on their side. The program is Wileyplus, it has been sub par from in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your computer has done,  But I know that you are right.

Comment: Just needed confirmation from someone else that the numbers were correct. thanks